# JSP - JS - Java interaction

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I am trying to call a method in a Java applet from JS. I am a little bit confused about how to arrange my workflow. I have a jsp (pending.jsp) class which includes a javascript (pending.js). pending.jsp is just a container to hold pending.js. pending.js' purpose is to enable users to cancel report creation.

pending.jsp:

```
<div id="pending-reports-container" class="pending-reports-container">

    <div id="pending-reports">

    </div>
</div>
```

pending.js:

```
function update_pending_reports(response_data)
{ bla }
function delete_report(report_id)
{ bla }
function request_pending_reports()
{ bla }
function start_pending_reports() {
    request_pending_reports();
    setInterval("request_pending_reports()", 5000);
}
```

Because cancelling reports sometimes is not that efficient I want to use Java to cancel requests that goes to the postgres (pending.js does not kill the process that works at postgres). I created my Java class but I don't know where to add it. I know I can make use of  tag, but when I tried to add this tag to my jsp file like this:

```
<div id="pending-reports-container" class="pending-reports-container">

    <div id="pending-reports">
       <applet id="LS" width=1 height=1 code ="module/LicenseCheckService.class" codebase="."/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can not reach it from my pending.js with this code:

```
 getJS = document.getElementById("LS");
```

Is there something wrong with my code or am I wrong at this structure in the first place?

Comment: Do not pass strings to `setInterval`. Pass functions instead: `setInterval(request_pending_reports, 5000);` or if you need arguments: `setInterval(function() { request_pending_reports(something);}, 5000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Invoking Applet Methods From JavaScript Code](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html) Oracle docs.

Nutshell version is that the JavaScript refers to the applet object by the applet ID, and can call methods on it.

```
appletId.anAppletMethod();
var anAppletClass = appletId.getAnAppletClass();
anAppletClass.methodCalled("with a JavaScript string parameter");
// Etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

See Dave Newton's answer.

**Alternatively**, you can also check the HTML field or call a javascript method from Applet. You can construct the interaction to be actively controlled by the applet.

Link here : [Java Applet To JS Link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html)